# Printing 60 characters per line

Tags: c, file, string-formatting, user-input

I have written a program that gets a text file from a user.

It should then print 60 characters a time then start on a new line, however, even though it works

some words go over this limit and then it cuts the word into half then starts

again on a new line. So I need my program to essentially figure out

whether that word would fit into the 60 character limit so no words are split up.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main( void )
{
char ch, file_name[25];
FILE *fp;
printf("Enter file name: \n");
scanf("%24s" ,file_name);

if ( (fp = fopen(file_name,"r")) == NULL ){
     perror("This file does not exist\n");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}

int c, count;

count = 0;
while ( (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF ) {
    if ( c == '\n' )
        putchar( ' ' );
    else
        putchar( c );

    count++;
    if ( count == 60 ) {
        putchar( '\n' );
        count = 0;
    }
}
putchar( '\n' );
fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but your code has a buffer overflow

Comment: 'no word is split up'.  OK, so you need to write down what a word is.  Then what defines the start and end of a word.  Then you can recognise if the 60th character is inside a word or not.

Comment: ..or, write down what a word is not.  One definition might be 'a word does not contain white space'.

Comment: `fgetc()` returns `int`, not `char`.

Comment: ..so if char 61 is whilte space, char 60 does not split a word.

Comment: ..and if char 60 is white space, char 60 does not split a word.

Comment: ..and then fix all your other bugs, and you're done.

Comment: Flagging as too broad because now you're asking us to solve the Kindle Text Problem (search the Youtube video)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could scan a word and if the line and word are less than 60, concatenate them. Otherwise print the line and copy the word to the line starting the process over again.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
    FILE *fp = NULL;
    char file_name[257] = {'\0'};
    char line[61] = {'\0'};
    char word[61] = {'\0'};
    int out = 0;

    printf ( "Enter file name:\n");
    scanf ( " %256[^\n]", file_name);

    if ( ( fp = fopen ( file_name, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf ( "could not open file\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while ( ( fscanf ( fp, "%60s", word)) == 1) {
        if ( strlen ( line) + strlen ( word) + 1 <= 60) {
            strcat ( line, " ");
            strcat ( line, word);
            out = 0;
        }
        else {
            printf ( "%s\n", line);
            strcpy ( line, word);
            out = 1;
        }
    }
    if ( !out) {
        printf ( "%s\n", line);
    }

    fclose ( fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int readWord(FILE *fp,char *buff,char *lastChar){
    char c;
    int n=-1;
    *buff=0;
    *lastChar=0;
    while((c= fgetc(fp))!=EOF){
        n++;
        if(isspace(c)){
            /*
                you may keep tabs or replace them with spaces
            */
            *lastChar=c;
            break;
        }       
        buff[n]=c;
        buff[n+1]=0;
    }
    return n;
}


int main( void ) {
    char ch, file_name[25];
    char buff[50];
    int pos=0;
    FILE *fp;
    printf("Enter file name: \n");
    gets(file_name);

    if ( !(fp = fopen(file_name,"r")) ) {
        perror("This file does not exist\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    int c, count;

    count = 0;
    while ( (pos=readWord(fp,buff,&ch))!=EOF) {
        count+=pos+(!!ch);
        if(count>60){
            printf("\n");
            count=pos;
        }

        if(ch){
            printf("%s%c",buff,ch);
        }else{
            printf("%s",buff);
        }
        if(!pos){
            count=0;
        }

    }
    putchar( '\n' );
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```